VBA- How to count number of colums in Excel
I am using VBA for the first time in a long time and looking to get an answer to something that may seem a bit basic.

I am looking to count how many columns my headers use
Store that value in a variable


I know that it is 7 but I do not know how to store that information in a variable.
my worksheet headers will vary from length to length

This seems like an XY problem. What's the end goal here?

@BigBen Looking to hightlight random rows in a dataset, but need to know how to calculate the end of the row first otherwise it highlights the entire worksheet

Then the linked thread is what you need.
